# Git pushed a commit of another user

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I'm working with IntelliJ IDE and every time I push my commits the push is "on" another user, the commits is on my-self but when I push it, the push is on another user.

We work with git-server, updated the ssh keys of git user and it keeps happen, any ideas?

[image: example]

"User 1" is the one the push is pushed on him, and I marked the commits because the commits is different user from the one who pushed it.
I did commits and the commits display like I commited it, but when I push, it pushed "on" User 1.

Comment: What do you mean by "on" another user? Are you talking about the author or committer fields of a commit? Or about branches? It's unclear. You  could provide some examples to explain what you mean.

Comment: sorry, I will update it with images.
I mean "on" like, the commits are on me, but the push is on another user.

Comment: That didn't make *anything* clearer for me.

Comment: @JoachimSauer added image for example

Comment: Still unclear. Can you tell us who "User 1" is? And why you underlined the commit ids? What's special/relevant about those? I don't know git-server and don't know if it displays the commit users or the actual user that pushed a given commit in this list. This screenshot shows only a single user, so where does the second user come into play?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Sorry, "User 1" is the user the commits are "pushed by" and I underlined the commit because it not write there but the image is different, if I look in the commit, this is me.
The commit is on me, but the push is on another user

Comment: What generated these images? Is this a browser snapshot, or from the IntelliJ IDE? Are you using GitHub or BitBucket or GitLab as a hosting site, or is the hosting site internal to the company?

Comment: +1 to Torek, there is a chance that hosting site can detect user by its email, so it's worth checking what user.email do you have specified in Git config. 
So please double-check:
1. What hosting platform do you use?
2. What user.email address do you have specified in git config?

Comment: This an image from hosting sire internal to the company.
I already set and config email to my email, everything is set to me, but for some reason, ONLY the pushes is writes on another user.
The commits is on me, but the push is on another.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation in the past with one of my companies. There is no issue with this; it is just extremely inconvenient if some of your colleagues want to see who did such a commit and they have "user1". Therefore, I strongly advise you to configure your own terminal git configuration if you never did such a thing (see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Commit_and_push_changes.html#git-username) and, if that does not resolve the issue, take a look at this issue with Jetbrain regarding unknown commuter usernames: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/upsource/resolving-username.html.

If that resolve your issue, do not forget to agreed the answer for others in the same case as you.

Cheers all.

Comment: I found them both before I wrote this post, unfortunately it not solved my issue, everything in my git config looks the same. the another link I think this is not my issue.

Comment: interesting, have you tried another jet brain solution if it does the same weird behaviour on your git history?

Comment: I tried it, but the issue in the jetbrains solution is not my issue, my issue is just the opposite, the push user is not correct and the commit is correct.